# Проверка, нахожусь ли я на странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Как мне отследить, находится ли пользователь на вкладке? Т.е. загружается страница, я нажимаю на другую вкладку браузера и на моей странице выполняется определённая функция. Когда я опять нажимаю на вкладку страницы, то выполняется другая функция

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это можно осуществить с помощью обычных событий focus и blur применив их к объекту window.

Пример:

```js
$(window).focus(function() {
  console.log( 'Вкладка открыта! :)' );
});
$(window).blur(function() {
  console.log( 'Вкладка не открыта! :(' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Пример без JQuery:

```js
window.onfocus = function() {
  console.log( 'Вкладка открыта! :)' );
};
window.onblur = function() {
  console.log( 'Вкладка не открыта! :(' );
};
```